# In Unity, Events in C# fire but suscriber methods don't?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, eventhandler

I'm having difficulties to connect my events fired to a suscriber method in another class. Here is the whole setup :

First, I got this class which act as the publisher class :

```
  public class OpenInteraction : IInteraction
  {
        public event EventHandler<bool> OpenStateChange;

        private void OnOpenStateChange(bool e)
        {
            Debug.Log("open = " + e);     
            OpenStateChange?.Invoke(this, e);
        }     
  }
```

I have a second class, which is supposed to be the suscriber :

```
    public class AttachedContainer : MonoBehaviour
    { 
        private OpenInteraction openInteraction;

        public void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log("create OpenInteraction in AttachedContainer");
            openInteraction = new OpenInteraction();
            openInteraction.OpenStateChange += ContainerOpened;    
        }

        static void ContainerOpened(object sender, bool e)
        {
            Debug.Log("container state changed");
        }
    }
```

For just a bit of context, the event is fired everytime I open/close a container in a game. The method `OnOpenStateChange(bool e)` is called properly when the player does that and the Debug console shows the message "open = .."

An openInteraction is created at the start of the game on every AttachedContainer, the message "create OpenInteraction in AttachedContainer" is appropriately Logged here too.

However, I never see the message "container state changed", inside the suscriber method, supposed to be fired everytime there's a close/open interaction.

What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious about what could be causing it. I can't reproduce the described problem from your instructions, I get the same result in unity as here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wG12eq . Consider starting an empty project, reproducing the problem then editing into this question including the steps necessary to do so. See [mre] for more information.  Of special note is that no helpful description of how `OnOpenStateChange` is called, only that it is called "properly" under certain conditions.

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks it's really useful to see that it works in a minimal example like the one you provided. I'd like to make one but this code is part of something much more complicated, it's networked, there's many interconnected scripts.. Regarding the call on OnOpenStateChange I just know that's it's called every time I perform an open/close action, as expected.

Comment: Is it possible that the instance where you registered the event and the one you are looking at are different ones? ;) Try to rather give it a name or unique ID when you create the `new OpenInteraction("some unique ID")` and then log that `Debug.Log($"{theID} open = {e}");`

Comment: @derHugo that's definitely the issue here, now I see it. I didn't solve it yet but that's definitely the way.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of the class OpenInteraction, which calls the event, and the instance of this class in the Class AttachedContainer muss be the same one.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, regarding the two instances. The second part of your answer, I knew that and I'm not making any call to it outside of the class OpenInteraction. If you edit you answer to get rid of the second part I'll take it as accepted :)

Comment: Okie, it depends on your logic for your project. Another possible resolution is that you make the event static. So you can raise the event from any instance.